# Postgresql timestamps

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

Currently I have one column of timestamps showing this now:
Tuesday, August 2, 2016 1:00 PM

these time stamps are not limited to 1 date but it shows various dates with different times. What I would like to do is edit these time stamps, whereby if the time shown is more than 10:20pm of the day, I would like to change the time portion to 10:20pm

Example:
Tuesday, August 2, 2016 23:21 PM **change to** Tuesday, August 2, 2016 22:20 PM
Tuesday, August 3, 2016 1:00 PM **no change**

Essentially, anything more than 22:20 for the day amend to 22:20 while anything earlier will just remain as they were before.

Comment: Take a look at this part of the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT Lots of good info there on manipulating dates. Basically extract the time component and compare it to 22:20, then create a new date with 22:20 time if it's over, and add it to the extracted date.

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1 
   set ts = date_trunc('day', ts) + '22:20:00'::interval
   where ts - date_trunc('day', ts) > '22:20:00'::interval
```